# WEKA is freezing after every click

Tags: weka

Whenever I click the weka option/button, weka **freezes**. I had not done anything but installed fresh weka 3.8.4 recently. Even when I  clicked explore, it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. One of the best ways to see errors occurring in Weka is to look at the "console" output. Please enter "weka with console" in the program search section. So you start Weka from console. Let's say it froze after the clicks you specified. You can now get clues about this situation by looking at the "console". Probably an exception occurs or Java installation is problematic.

As another solution, try downloading Weka with integrated java. You can find it in the link below.

Click [here](https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/weka/weka-3-8-4-azul-zulu-windows.exe) to download a self-extracting executable for 64-bit Windows that includes Azul's 64-bit OpenJDK Java VM 11 (weka-3-8-4-azul-zulu-windows.exe; 118 MB)

For details: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/downloading_weka/

It can help you understand what is happening as it will be independent of Java in your operating system. If it works, it means Java in your operating system at the root of your problem.

Good luck.